# Apache Beam Wall Time keeps increasing

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have a Beam pipeline that reads from a pubsub topic, does some small transformations and then writes the events to some BigQuery tables.

The transforms are light on processing, maybe removing a field or something else, but, as you can see from the image below, the Wall Time is very high for some steps. What can actually cause this?

Every element is actually a tuple of the form `((str, str, str), {**dict with data})`. By this key we actually try to do a naive deduplication by taking the latest event by this key.
Basically whatever I add after that `Get latest element per key` is slow, and tagging is also slow, even tho it just adds a tag to the element.

[image: pipeline screen]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By "slow" I assume you mean how many elements it processes per second?

There are two things that are going on here. First, I assume that `Get latest element per key` contains a GroupByKey of sorts. This involves a global shuffle, with all elements being sent over the network to other elements, to ensure all elements with a given key are grouped onto the same worker. This IO can be expensive, at least in terms of wall time.

Secondly, steps that don't need worker-to-worker communication are "fused" which couples their throughputs. E.g. if one has `DoFnA` followed by `DoFnB` followed by `DoFnC`, the processing proceeds by passing the first element through `DoFnA`, then passing those outputs to `DoFnB` and subsequently `DoFnC` before getting the second element to pass to `DoFnA`. This means that if one of the Fns (or the reading or writing) has a bounded throughput, all of them will.

Comment: Thanks for explanation. Yes, that grouping is done by `combiners.Latest.PerKey()` and from my observations is doing quite ok in terms of elements per second. The main bottleneck is basically whatever comes after this step. Now is that reshuffle, before this was tagging.
I just have one question:
 - How do I know that some steps are fusion together?

Don't know if it helps, bug here is a job id `2020-12-09_08_32_30-16230074399558339654` :)

Comment: I'm actually not sure there's a place to go to see which stages got fused, but typically it's everything between two GBKs. Usually it's not something you need to worry about.

Comment: Update: if you click on a step in the Dataflow UI, at the bottom of the right StepInfo panel, there's a section called "Optimized Stages." Steps that are fused together will be in the same optimized stage (e.g F__). Note that some steps may span optimized stages.

Comment: Gotcha. And how about the Wall time? Should I worry about it? I mean, the job runs for 48h and it has some crazy wall times, like the Reshuffle stage has 50 days and the Tag Value has 13 days... Some crazy numbers and I am not sure if I should worry about :)

Comment: Walltime can be a useful signal, but especially if there's IO involved I would not worry about it. (Streaming pipelines are highly multi-threaded, and it's the sum of walltime over each threads.)